# Error installing gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting an error when installing certain gems. I am using ubuntu 10.10. The error messages shows this.

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
undefined method `spec' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Please provide more details of what your ruby version is what all gems you are trying to install

Comment: ruby 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) [i686-linux]
gem version 1.3.7

Comment: What gem? All I can see so far is it might be that you don't have the RSpec gem installed. Really hard to tell with such an uninformative question... If you want an informative answer, please ask informative questions.

Comment: It's been solved. Downloading the gem and installing it locally does the trick.

Comment: You should really delete this question. It serves no purpose

Comment: This question and it's answers helped me a lot. Please do not delete it.

Comment: I disagree about the reason this question was closed. It has apparently helped many people considering how many up-votes the top answer has. I would have posted my answer, but since I can't here's how I fixed it: considering I use rvm, I decided to delete the current and global gemsets using `rvm gemset delete <gemset>` and then running `bundle`. Quicker than @jensendarren's answer.

Answer (score 38):

I had exactly the same error as this...

While installing Rails 3 my computer suffered a power outage. After restarting the computer and continuing the Rails 3 installation the process failed with this exact same error. The problem was due to the gem install cache which had corrupted / empty gem files. My solution was to clear this cache and run the install again, as follows:

1. Find out the location of your cache using `gem env`
2. List all the gems in that cache, e.g. `ls -l /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/cache/`
3. Compare with successfully installed gems using `gem list`
4. Remove the gems from the cache list that are missing from the gem list e.g. using `rm`
5. I also had to remove some empty / corrupt gemspec files from the specification directory `ls -l /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications/`
6. Continue the installation, e.g. `sudo gem install -v=3.0.6 rails --no-rdoc --no-ri`

Hope this helps someone else who has a power outage or other external failure during a gem install process!

Comment: A system crash left some gems filled with blank hex. Clearing out the `specifications` and `cache` folders seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: Sir, you are a true hero! You just saved a life :)
I was having this issue on my mac 10.10 for quite a few days and none of the solutions I came across were working. But this is it. Perfect!

Much much thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Some gems rely on other gems to run, but haven't been setup correctly to automatically install them (ie they haven't had their dependencies correctly set).

You'll often only find out when you try to run them... just like this.

luckily the error message here makes it fairly clear that you need the "rspec" gem installed...  and as you've already discovered, the solution is simply to install the missing gem.

Other gems aren't often as easy to figure out, but googling for the error message (or putting it up on StackOverflow) usually sorts it out pretty quick.