# Getting "isn't a Gem::Specification (NilClass instead)" when running after gem --version

Tags: ruby, rubygems

```
$ gem --version

[/home/rohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@qnrDashboard/specifications/net-ssh-2.5.2.gemspec] isn't a Gem::Specification (NilClass instead).
[/home/rohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@qnrDashboard/specifications/net-sftp-2.0.5.gemspec] isn't a Gem::Specification (NilClass instead).
[/home/rohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@qnrDashboard/specifications/net-ssh-gateway-1.1.0.gemspec] isn't a Gem::Specification (NilClass instead).
[/home/rohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@qnrDashboard/specifications/net-scp-1.0.4.gemspec] isn't a Gem::Specification (NilClass instead).
```

Using RVM 1.12.3, RubyGems 1.8.22, & Ruby 1.9.3.

Why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. the problem i think is with cache of the gems. try the steps in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999683/error-installing-gems) might solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

On windows,

```
cd C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems
rm -rf ./*
cd ..\specifications
rm -rf /*
```

Then finally,

```
gem install rails
```

This problem started happening after Windows decided that there was an error and restarted with that pretty blue screen.