# Rails installation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to install Rails on Mac OS (Mavericks) but for some reason it won't let me.  I already have Ruby installed.  Here is the error and set of gems I already have:

```
[~] ruby-2.2.1 $ sudo gem install rails
Password:
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
invalid gem: package is corrupt, exception while verifying: undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) in /Users/garrettgalvin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/cache/nokogiri-1.6.6.2.gem

actionview (4.2.3)
activesupport (4.2.3)
bigdecimal (1.2.6)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.10.5)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
erubis (2.7.0)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
i18n (0.7.0)
io-console (0.4.3)
json (1.8.1)
loofah (2.0.2)
mini_portile (0.6.2)
minitest (5.7.0)
psych (2.0.8)
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails-dom-testing (1.0.6)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rubygems-update (2.4.8)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If the package is corrupt you may need to install it again. Does it always do this? Are you able to visit [Rubygems](https://rubygems.org/) without it being redirected somewhere?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use sudo when installing gems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install Rails Error "invalid gem: package is corrupt"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850737/install-rails-error-invalid-gem-package-is-corrupt)

Comment: Don't do `sudo gem install rails`. That will install Rails into Apple's installed Ruby, which is there for their use. Instead, use RVM or rbenv to install Ruby in a sandbox, then install Rails there using `gem install rails`.

Comment: @theTinMan actually this depends on the setup, it may install in the correct location, but mess up the file permissions

Comment: The OP is using RVM to manage Ruby. The RVM authors specifically say to NOT use `sudo` when installing gems.

Answer (score 0):

You should never install gems using `sudo`.

If, while installing your package, you get any gem corruption errors, then you have to do the installation again and make sure you delete the respective gem in the .rvm file. (Search and delete all of the gems with that name.)