# "NoMethod" error when installing Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to terminal so please bear with me. I'm having trouble installing Rails. I think it's because I interrupted a previous installation. Now I keep running into this error:

`Error installing rails:
    invalid gem: package is corrupt, exception while verifying: undefined method` `'size' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/cache/mail-2.6.3.gem`

I've uninstalled the gems that were installed in the first installation, but the error still exists. The gems I uninstalled were:

```
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)`
rails-dom-testing (1.0.5)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.1)
sprockets-rails (2.2.4)
```

edit: This issue was solved by: `rm /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/cache/mail-2.6.3.gem` and rebooting the machine. The reason for the error was a corrupt cached file.

Comment: what is the commnd you are running?

Answer (score 5):

[This solution worked for me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999683/error-installing-gems)

To quote [jensendarren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76077/jensendarren)'s solution:

> While installing Rails 3 my computer suffered a power outage. After
>   restarting the computer and continuing the Rails 3 installation the
>   process failed with this exact same error. The problem was due to the
>   gem install cache which had corrupted / empty gem files. My solution
>   was to clear this cache and run the install again, as follows:
>
> 1. Find out the location of your cache using `gem env`
> 2. List all the gems in that cache, e.g. `ls -l /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/cache/`
> 3. Compare with successfully installed gems using `gem list`
> 4. Remove the gems from the cache list that are missing from the gem list e.g. using `rm`
> 5. I also had to remove some empty / corrupt gemspec files from the specification directory `ls -l /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications/`
> 6. Continue the installation, e.g. `sudo gem install -v=3.0.6 rails --no-rdoc --no-ri`

Answer (score 1):

locate cache using gem env

List all the gems in that cache, using

```
ls -l /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/cache/
```

Compare with installed gems using

```
gem list
```

Remove the gems from the cache list that are missing from the gem list  using `rm` command

Continue the installation, using

```
gem install -v=version_u_want rails --no-rdoc --no-ri
```